# Paypal accounts funded by credit cards = 10417 error

Tags: paypal

I've come here in a bid to try and solve what seems like a blackhole that nobody in paypal can help us with.

We've a business account. Paypal Express (digital goods). Verified, restrictions lifted etc...
We've got paypal express integrated fine as our sole payment method. But there's a problem. ANY paypal account funded by a credit card will just flat out fail and give a 10417 error.

**Overview**

- Customer A has an existing paypal balance of $10
- Customer B has an existing paypal balance of $0 but has their account
  funded by credit card.
- Customer A has no problems on our site with any transaction below $10.
- Customer B gets an error upon payment. More specifically, a 10417 error.

Now before anyone says it, we have checked with card issuers etc... so we're 100% sure this is not an error with cards or banks (as the 10417 error tends to suggest). We've literally tested this with a dozen verified / clean paypal accounts in different countries with different card types & different issuing banks. All of them fail and sandbox gives us no clues either...

Can anyone throw us a bone here or think of any possible reason this could be happening? It would be much appreciated...

***Update: Resolved:*** Turns out it was a problem with our account and more specifically our category of industry. It would have helped of course had someone told me that the half a dozen or so times I called over the past week - yesterday on the phone i asked an agent if she was 100% certain this was a problem with a customers card, bank or billing address. I knew it wasn't so i wanted just to see if she'd commit to it. Her response - "yes sir, i'm 100% certain". Sums it all up. Hopefully this will help someone else out there... if you're getting 10417 errors, try changing the business category or subcategory in a bid to stop you going insane...

Comment: Have you reviewed [this thread](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/eBay-and-PayPal-Archive/Error-Code-10417-Your-request-could-not-be-processed-at-this/td-p/186550)?  Seems like there are a couple of possible solutions in there.

Comment: Yes, we've reviewed everything and towards the end of the 125 pages, most people's problem turned out to be 'verified by visa / securecode'  simply not being set up properly with their banks. The problem we have is that all cards are failing yet these cards are working fine on other sites to buy things through paypal... it's not a problem with cards or banks.

Comment: Hi Sir, a long dead topic here, but any chance you can ping me on this topic? We are getting huge numbers of 10417 Errors, shannon -at- sprfrkr.com. Thank you kindly.

Comment: you are making me even more insane by not explaining 'try changing the business category or subcategory in a bid to stop you going insane...' - I don't expect a reply since I see your account is inactive but if anybody else figures this out please post what was it before and what you changed it to

Comment: in my case the business was categorised as a gambling related business so that meant it came with more restrictions than any other category... we changed the category and the problems went away, therefore we figured out the business category was the issue - paypal had / have some automated restrictions in place based on the business category...

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the exact same issue, paypal support was not very helpful

Turns out the problem was the business URL was set to http instead of https

Our business website redirects from http -> https, but this redirect seems to cause a problem at checkout for paypal

Once we changed the business url, customers were able to proceed with payments

Solution:

- Log in to paypal
- Navigate to https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/info/edit
- Edit the business profile and make sure "Business URL" is set to https://