# 40% Failure Rate with PayPal SetExpressCheckout API

Tags: paypal

I am hoping someone with experience can help here. We are sending people to PayPal using SetExpressCheckout and then billing them when they get back to our site. Unfortunately, we are seeing a 40% failure rate when we attempt to charge these users. I am including our request and responses below in the hopes that someone can spot a variable that may be causing some trouble for us.

Thanks!

```
REQUEST TO PAYPAL TO SET EXPRESS CHECKOUT: 
SetExpressCheckoutReq:
SetExpressCheckoutRequest:
Version: 116.0
SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails:
MaxAmount currencyID="USD”: 100
ReqConfirmShipping: 0
NoShipping: 1
AddressOverride: 0
SolutionType: Sole
BuyerEmail: xxx
BillingAgreementDetails:
BillingType: MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement
BillingAgreementDescription: Billing Agreement
PaymentDetails:
OrderTotal currencyID="USD”:0
ItemTotal currencyID="USD”: 0
ButtonSource: PayPal_SDK 
PaymentDetailsItem: 
Name: Subscription 
Quantity: 1
Amount currencyID="USD”:0
PaymentDetailsItem:
PaymentAction: Authorization


RESPONSE: 
Timestamp: 2015-06-30T02:35:29Z
Ack: Success
CorrelationID: xxx
Version: 116.0
Build: 16684246
Token: XXX


BILLING ATTEMPT: 
DoReferenceTransactionRequest:
Version: 53.0
DoReferenceTransactionRequestDetails:
ReferenceID: EC-1WA3806198386283U 
PaymentAction: Sale
PaymentType: Any
PaymentDetails:
OrderTotal currencyID='USD’: 14.95
OrderDescription: Subscription
NotifyURL: xxx
ReqConfirmShipping: 0


ERROR RESPONSE: 
Short Message : Transaction cannot complete.
Long Message:Instruct the customer to retry the transaction using an alternative payment method from the customers PayPal wallet. The transaction did not complete with the customers selected payment method.
ErrorCode:10417
SeverityCode: Error
CorrelationId:907fc42ce9669
Build:17098556
Ip:
```

Comment: This is an odd way to do this. Normally you'd run SEC -> bounce w/ token -> return from Paypal -> run `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`. My understanding on reference transactions with Express Checkout is that you need a Billing Agreement first.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to change with your parameters, but also see the last item:

1. You are requesting version 116 (relatively modern) for SetEC and version 56 (circa 2005, ie 10 years old!!) for DoEC. It's unlikely that this is causing your issues, but I would still fix it :)
2. Your SetEC is for a biling agreement but your DoEC is for a sale transaction. Don't mix and match these, it screws up PayPal's ability to set the funding correctly. If you are just doing a sale, remove the billing agreement from the SetEC and....
3. update your SetEC to specify a nonzero amount, hopefully close (within +- 20%) of your actual DoEC amount. PayPal may be defaulting customers to the wrong funding source, or letting them through without correcting fixable account issues (such as an expired or otherwise unusable credit card) because you told PayPal that the payment would be for $0, and only when you actually DoEC for $14 does PayPal discover that the buyer doesn't have the money for you.

And finally:

There can be many things that cause 10417 -- it is a risk response, meaning that PayPal is deciding to decline the transaction.

See e.g. [Paypal accounts funded by credit cards = 10417 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561078/paypal-accounts-funded-by-credit-cards-10417-error), in which another seller was having lots of declines because they were selling in a very high risk category. Not sure what your account is set up as, but something like this could be affecting you... if you continue getting a 40% rejection rate with natural user traffic after cleaning up your API calls I would contact PayPal support.

Comment: Thank you kindly for this. Very helpful indeed. I will update the version, I do recall I had some issues completing the call with a newer version, I will see if we can fix it. Also, we are not billing the user until after their 30 day trial, which is why no amount is being setup in SetEC. I was just trying to create the billing agreement in the first step with no charge. (I know that was not clear in my first post). Any thoughts? Do you have time to consult on this? My username at gmail is my email. TIA.

Comment: @geezwizSir, any chance I could pay you for some consulting work on this issue? Still seeing a huge failure rate. My email is my username at gmail. Thank you kindly.